# USART displays only half values when VCC is plugged in and repeats the same after VCC is removed

Tags: pic, i2c, uart, accelerometer, gyro

I'm trying to interface mpu6050 module with pic16f886 microcontroller. But, nothing's getting displayed on serial monitor. USART code works fine when used separately, but when added with the i2c and MPU code it doesn't work. As you can see in my main code below, i have added `usart_send_byte('1');` and so on after every function call to test if my code is working fine. But it doesn't print anything on the serial monitor. I'm using coolterm and putty to read the data.
kindly help.

**EDIT: For some reason, i'm getting only half the values when VCC is plugged in and the same in repeated after i remove  my vcc. It's shown in picture.**
**When VCC plugged in -**[image: When VCC plugged in]**  When VCC removed  [image: When VCC removed]

**pic config **

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTRC_CLKOUT       
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled and can be enabled by SWDTEN bit of the WDTCON register)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // RE3/MCLR pin function select bit (RE3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown Out Reset Selection bits (BOR enabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF        // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB3 pin has digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config BOR4V = BOR40V   // Brown-out Reset Selection bit (Brown-out Reset set to 4.0V)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Self Write Enable bits (Write protection off)


#include <xc.h> 
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define I2C_SPEED 100000
#define baud 9600
```

**sourc.c**

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "all_header.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define I2C_SPEED 100000
#define baud 9600

//usart

void usart_init(){
    TRISC6=0;
    TRISC7=1;
//    SPBRG=_XTAL_FREQ/(16*baud) -1;
    SPBRG=25;                                                                   //pg.no - 163
    TXSTAbits.BRGH=1;
    TXSTAbits.SYNC=0;
    RCSTAbits.SPEN=1;
    TXSTAbits.TXEN=1;
    RCSTAbits.CREN=1;
    TXSTAbits.TX9=0;
    RCSTAbits.RX9=0;
    RCSTAbits.FERR = 0;     // Disable framing error
    RCSTAbits.OERR = 0;     // Disable overrun error

}

void usart_send_byte(char bt){
    while(TXIF==0);
    TXREG=bt;
}


void usart_send_string(char* str) {
    while(*str!= '\0')
        usart_send_byte(*str++);
}

//i2c

void i2c_init(void){
    TRISC3=1;
    TRISC4=1;

    SSPADD= ((_XTAL_FREQ/4)/I2C_SPEED)-1;
    SSPSTAT=0x80;
    SSPCON=0x28;
    SSPCON2=0x00;
}

void i2c_start_write(char slave_add){
    while(1){
    SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1;            /* Send START condition */
    while(SSPCON2bits.SEN);         /* Wait for completion of START */
    SSPIF = 0;
    if(!SSPSTATbits.S)              /* Continue if START is failed */
        continue;
    i2c_write(slave_add);           /* Write slave device address with write to communicate */
    if(ACKSTAT)                     /* Check whether Acknowledgment received or not */
    {
        i2c_stop();                 /* If not then initiate STOP and continue */
        continue;
    }    
    break;                          /* If yes then break loop */
    }
}

int i2c_restart_write(char slave_add){
    RSEN = 1;                                                                   /* Send REPEATED START condition */
    while(SSPCON2bits.RSEN);                                                    /* Wait for completion of REPEATED START condition */
    SSPIF = 0;
    if(!SSPSTATbits.S)                                                          /* Return 0 if REPEATED START is failed */
    return 0;
    i2c_write(slave_add);                                                       /* Write slave device address with read to communicate */
    if (ACKSTAT)                    /* Return 2 if acknowledgment received else 1 */
     return 1;
    else
     return 2;
}

void i2c_stop(void){
    SSPCON2bits.PEN=1;
    while(!SSPIF);
    SSPIF=0;
}

void i2c_ack(){
    ACKDT=0;
    ACKEN=1;
    while(ACKEN);
}

void i2c_nack(){
    ACKDT=1;
    ACKEN=1;
    while(ACKEN);
}

int i2c_write(unsigned char data){
    SSPBUF=data;
    while(!SSPIF);
    SSPIF=0;
    return ACKSTAT;
}

unsigned char i2c_read(unsigned ack){
    SSPCON2bits.RCEN=1;
    while(!SSPIF);
    SSPIF=0;
    if (ack)
        i2c_ack();
    else
        i2c_nack();
    return SSPBUF;
}

void bytewrite(unsigned char slave_add_write, unsigned char add, unsigned char data)
{

    i2c_start_write(slave_add_write);                   //Generate Start COndition
    i2c_write(add);                          
    i2c_write(data);                    
    i2c_stop();                         // send Stop
}

void byteread(unsigned char slave_add_write, unsigned char slave_add_read, unsigned char add, unsigned char *data, unsigned char length)
{

    i2c_start_write(slave_add_write);
    i2c_write(add);                
    i2c_restart_write(slave_add_read);  

    while(length-- > 1)
    *(data++) = i2c_read(1);            // Read one byte
    *(data++) = i2c_read(0);
    i2c_stop();
}

//mpu6050

void mpu_init(){
    //__delay_ms(150); removed while edit

    usart_send_string("1");
    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(SMPLRT_DIV);                                                      //write to sample rate register(write to this address)
    i2c_write(0x07);                                                            //1KHZ sample rate(write to data)
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(PWR_MGMT_1);
    i2c_write(0x01);                                                            //x-axis gyro reference frequency
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(CONFIG);
    i2c_write(0x01);                                                            //fs=1KHZ
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(GYRO_CONFIG);
    i2c_write(0x18);                                                            //full scale range +/- 2000 deg/c
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(INT_ENABLE);
    i2c_write(0x01);
    i2c_stop();
    usart_send_string("2");
}

void mpu_start(){
    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(ACCEL_XOUT_H);                                                    //start from where to read
    i2c_restart_write(0xD1);                                                    /* I2C start with device read address */
    usart_send_string("3");

}

//main

void main(){
    char buffer[20];
    int ax,ay,az,gx,gy,gz,T;
    float xa,ya,za,xg,yg,zg,t;
    OSCCON=0x64;                                                                //4MHZ and internal clock
    usart_init();
    usart_send_byte('1');
    i2c_init();
    usart_send_byte('2');
    mpu_init();
     usart_send_byte('3');


    while(1){
        usart_send_byte('4');
        mpu_start();
        usart_send_byte('5');
        ax=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        ay=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        az=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        T=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        gx=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        gy=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        gz=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(1));                            //no ack . hence, stop read

        usart_send_byte('6');

        i2c_stop();

        usart_send_byte('7');

        xa =(float)ax/16384.0;
        ya =(float)ay/16384.0;
        za =(float)az/16384.0;
        t=((float)T/340.00)+36.53;
        xg=(float)gx/131.0;
        yg=(float)gx/131.0;
        zg=(float)gx/131.0;        

        usart_send_byte('8');

        sprintf(buffer,"ax=%.2f g\t",xa);                                       //Take values in buffer and send it over to Usart
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"ay=%.2f g\t",ya);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"az=%.2f g\t",za);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"T = %.2f%cC\t",t,0xF8);                                 /* 0xF8 Ascii value of degree '°' on serial */                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer," Gx = %.2f%c/s\t",xg,0xF8);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer," Gy = %.2f%c/s\t",yg,0xF8);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer," Gz = %.2f%c/s\t",zg,0xF8);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: In CoolTerm, do you have the receive option 'wait for termination string' turned off?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: Not earlier. But i do now. Still having the same issue.

Comment: "**nothing's** getting displayed on serial monitor." - yet the screenshots seem to show something _is_ getting displayed. The display might be easier to read if you replace each \t with \r\n. What are the PIC's config settings? Please show a schematic and/or photo of your setup.

Comment: @BruceAbbott: Question's been edited since i got that output.Also, pic's config has been updated. Please check.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.